# Execute curl in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

I need to execute this command in Python:

```
curl "http://robot:<automation secret>@127.0.0.1/monitor/check_mk/webapi.py?action=edit_host" -d 'request={"attributes": {"tag_check_puppet": "check_puppet"}, "hostname":"test.test.ch"}'
```

Problem is i'm new to python and it needs to be dynamic, so i can adapt it with variables like the hostname and tag_check_puppet value.

Any idea how to help me?

Comment: curl converters: http://curl.trillworks.com/ and https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/ . Or use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: oh well that makes it easy. Thank you!

Comment: @Damon, did you check my answer?

Comment: @Dekel yes i did, sorry for the long time, i was on holidays.. can you put it in as an answer to i can check it as correct?

Comment: It's already in the answer :) check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) for that:

```
import requests
requests.post("http://robot:<automation secret>@127.0.0.1/monitor/check_mk/webapi.py?action=edit_host", data={"attributes": {"tag_check_puppet": "check_puppet"}, "hostname":"test.test.ch"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to working with `curl`, you might want to try out the [pyCURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html) package.